# Add external JS engine to Eclipse runtime to use Eclipse Java Compiler and <script> in Ant in Java 15

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, nashorn

I have an Ant script with some `<script>` tasks and it is supposed to run with:

```
-Djavac.compiler=org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter
```

That is, it relies on running in the same JRE as Eclipse. When I try to launch this Ant script in the latest Eclipse it fails with:

```
Java 15 has removed Nashorn, you must provide an engine for running JavaScript yourself.
BUILD FAILED
buildJars.xml:86: Unable to create javax script engine for javascript
```

I downloaded Nashorn and its dependency jars and added them to the Ant runtime in Window/Preferences, but it didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Download nashorn-core-15.0.jar and its dependencies (with maven). Copy all jars into a known place, say `C:/keep/eclipse/nashorn`
Edit `eclipse.ini` and add below `-vmargs`:

```
--module-path=C:/keep/eclipse/nashorn
--add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH
```

Don't replace the existing `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM`. That one is required by Eclipse